# Learning ArcGIS Server programming?

Tags: arcgis-server, c#, references, asp.net

I'm new in programming c# and and arcgis server . i just use arcgis server wizard to create services and web applications but now i'd like to learn more about arcgis server and programming with asp.net . I just found programming arcgis server with asp.net book. i didn't buy this book .i coudln't find any website about learning arcgis server .

Can you recommend other resources to learn arcgis server programming for beginners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the site:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/serveradf_net/conceptualhelp/index.html

With Visual Studio 2010 (VS10) you can create a project ArcGIS (you need to install a package from ESRI to use this).

You can also create a project via ArcGIS Server Manager. Then you can open it in VS10 and play with it to understand the structure.

You can download a trial version of VS on the Microsoft website.

Answer (score 0):

You can learn ArcGIS Server step by step from [resource ArcGIS](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/Welcome_to_the_ArcGIS_10_2_for_Server_Windows_Help/0154000002np000000/) which includes:

- Setting up your server
- Publishing a service
- Creating a web application
- Configuring security